# Can $X+\operatorname{tr}(X)I$ be expressed as $WXW^\top$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can $X+\operatorname{tr}(X)I$ be expressed as $WXW^\top$ for arbitrary diagonal matrix $X$ with strictly positive diagonal elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments on the answer, it seems that you are asking whether there exists a matrix $W$  such that $X + \operatorname{tr}(X)I = W^TXW$ for all positive diagonal matrices $X$. The answer to this question is no.

Here's an argument that this should be the case. Suppose that $W$ is a suitable matrix, and let $n$ denote the size of the matrix $X$. Now, check what happens in the case that $X = I$: we find that
$$
I + \operatorname{tr}(I)I = W^TIW \implies W^T W = (1 + n)I.
$$
Thus, we find that the matrix $\frac 1{\sqrt{1 + n}}\cdot W$ is an orthogonal matrix. Letting $V = \frac 1{\sqrt{1 + n}}\cdot W$, we can rerwite the desired relationship as
$$
X + \operatorname{tr}(X)I = (n+1) V^TXV \implies V^TXV = \frac{X + \operatorname{tr}(X)I}{n+1}.
$$
Now, in order for these two sides to be the same, the matrices on each side must have the same eigenvalues. With that in mind, compare the eigenvalues of each matrix to the eigenvalues of $X$. Because $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, the eigenvalues of $V^TXV$ are the same as $X$. On the other hand, the eigenvalues of the matrix on the right are of the form $\frac{\lambda + \operatorname{tr}(X)}{n+1}$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $X$ (to verify that this is the case, consider what happens when you multiply $\frac{X + \operatorname{tr}(X)I}{n+1}$ by an eigenvector of $X$).

So, since $X$ can have any positive eigenvalues, the equality of these matrices implies the following: for any collection of eigenvectors $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, the collection $\frac{\lambda_1 + \operatorname{tr}(X)}{n+1},\dots,\frac{\lambda_n + \operatorname{tr}(X)}{n+1}$ consists of the same values.

I think it's intuitively clear that this should not always be the case. For a simple counterexample, suppose that $X = \operatorname{diag}(1,2)$. The corresponding eigenvalues of the right hand side are
$$
\frac{1 + 3}{3} = \frac 43, \quad \frac{2 + 3}{3} = \frac 53,
$$
which is clearly a different collection of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. The transformation $X\mapsto WXW^t$ corresponds to the transformation of the bilinear form $X(u,v)=u^tXv$ under a change of basis $v\mapsto W^tv$. So, if $X=\operatorname{diag}(x_1,...,x_n)$, with $x_i> 0$, then $X+\operatorname{tr}(X)I=\operatorname{diag}(x_1+\operatorname{tr}(X),...,x_n+\operatorname{tr}(X))$, where $x_i+\operatorname{tr}(X)> 0$ also. Crucially, the bilinear forms represented by $X$ and $X+\operatorname{tr}(X)I$ are both positive definite, and hence are equivalent under some change of basis (they have the same signature).

The two forms are

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iu_iv_i$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+\operatorname{tr}(X))u_iv_i$$

Since both are diagonal, the required change of coordinates can also be taken to be diagonal. $W=\operatorname{diag}(w_i)$, so we require
$$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i^2x_iu_iv_i\overset{!}{=}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+\operatorname{tr}(X))u_iv_i$$
giving
$$w_i=\sqrt{1+\frac{\operatorname{tr(X)}}{x_i}}$$

Therefore, $X+\operatorname{tr}(X)=WXW^t$ with $X=\operatorname{diag}(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $W=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{1+\frac{\operatorname{tr(X)}}{x_1}},...,\sqrt{1+\frac{\operatorname{tr(X)}}{x_n}})$.

Comment: Thanks! I mean that I need a $W$ independent of $X$. In other words, I want to rewrite the linear transformation $+\operatorname{tr}()$ in the form of $WXW^\top$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How could $W$ be independent of $X$?

Comment: For example, the linear transformation $f(X)=WXW^\top$ can be rewrote as $f(X) = A \operatorname{Vec}(X)$. Here, $A$ is not defined by $X$ but defined by $f$ itself. So, I want to know if the linear transformation $f(X) = X + \operatorname{tr}(X)I$ can be rewrot as $f(X) = WXW^\top, \forall X$ diagonally positive.

Comment: `I want to know if the linear transformation $f(X)=X+\operatorname{tr}(X)$ can be rewrot as $f(X)=WXW^t$, $\forall X$ diagonally positive' that is exactly what I have answered, in the affirmative, above.

Comment: @JoshuTilley What OP seems to be trying to ask is if there exists a single, specific $W$ (whose entries are constant rather than functions of $x_i$) such that for every diagonally positive matrix $X$, $X + \operatorname{tr}(X)I$ is equal to $WXW^T$. I suspect the answer is no